# css3 animation doesn`t apply to image

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I try to animate a resizing menu, it animates the div, but not the resizing of the image.
When I scroll down, the div has a nice transition, but the image resizes instantly.

What needs to be added for the transition to be applied to the image as well?

HTML markup:

```
<div class="col-md-3 logo">
    <img class="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-svg.svg">
</div>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'main','menu_class'=> 'meniu col-md-7 col-md-offset-2')); ?>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
if($(document).scrollTop()>100){
    $("header").addClass("small");
    $(".logo img").addClass("img-small");
    $("ul.meniu").addClass("small-nav")
} else{
    $("header").removeClass("small");
    $(".logo img").removeClass("img-small");
    $("ul.meniu").removeClass("small-nav")
}
```

CSS:

```
.img-small{
    width: 160px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
}

.small{
    height: 100px;
}

.small-nav{
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have not specified a `width` or `height` for the image before `.small` is applied to it, it is defaulting to `auto` (which in this case means "the original size of the image").

`auto` cannot be transitioned.

Solution: specify a `width` and `height` in the CSS of the image, which will be overridden and thus transitioned by the class.